# How does the img tag in an android webview display the images in the sdcard?

Tags: javascript, android

I use webview to load an html page. In this html page, I need to load an image from the sdcard. How can I do this?

```
mCaramerLauncher = mActivity.registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture(), new ActivityResultCallback<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(Boolean result) {
        JsonObject rsJson = new JsonObject();
        if(result){
            rsJson.addProperty("uri", imgUri.toString());
            rsJson.addProperty("code", 0);
        }else{
            rsJson.addProperty("data", "");
            rsJson.addProperty("code", 1);
        }
        jsCallParam.mCallback.callback(baseTMFWeb, rsJson.toString());
    }
});
```

I take a picture,get the uri,and send to the js,but img tag in the html can not show this uri.what can I do?

```
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
```

I set this ,not worked

Comment: `imgUri.toString())` What is imgUri?

Comment: And we see no img tag.